# Generating class of the $\sigma-$algebra of symmetric sets (with respect to the origin)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the $\sigma-$algebra of symmetric Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to the origin and 
$\mathcal{I}=\{(-a,a):~a>0\}$. True or false? $\sigma(\mathcal{I})=\mathcal{S}.$

Some thoughts: I believe it is correct. The inclusion $\sigma(\mathcal{I})\subseteq \mathcal{S}$ is fairly easy to prove, but I am stuck on the inverse, i.e. how to prove that every Borel symmetric subset of the reals can be written in terms of intervals of the form $(-a,a)$ (or their complements).

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: What can you say about $\{-1,1\}\in \mathcal{S}$?

Comment: Thanks for posting @sinbadh. I could say that it belongs to $\sigma(\mathcal{I})$, since is the intersection of the sets $(-1,1)^c,$ and $\displaystyle \Big(-1-1/n,1+1/n\Big),~n\geq1.$

Comment: Yes, I mean that: $$\{-1,1\}=(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,+\infty)\cap [-1,1]=(\mathbb{R}\setminus (-1,1))\cap \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(-1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\Big).$$

Comment: Ok. Now, you have $[-a,a]\in\sigma(I)$ for all $a>0$. Now, if $(-b,-a)\cup(a,b)\in\mathcal{S}$, show that $(-b,-a)\cup(a,b)\in\sigma(\mathcal{I})$.

Comment: (This is beside the point, but pleasant: in fact, you only need $(-a,a)$ for rational $a$.) To prove the reverse inclusion, it's enough to show that every symmetric *open* set is in $\sigma(\mathcal{I})$.

Comment: @sinbadh, of course this is valid since for $0<a<b$: $(-b,-a)\cup (a,b)=(-b,b)\cap [-a,a]^c$. The thing is: these sets, meaning  $(-b,-a)\cup (a,b),$ generate (of course) $\mathcal{S}$ (which would give us $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{I}))$, but could this be done?

Comment: @BrianO thanks for posting! Your remark is true, indeed, rationals are enough.

Comment: Probably the most direct approach is to note that every $B$ in $\mathcal S$ is $B=A\cup(-A)$ with $A$ in $\mathcal B([0,+\infty))$ and that $\mathcal B([0,+\infty))=\sigma(\mathcal J)$ with $\mathcal J=\{[0,a)\mid a\geqslant0\}$. The result follows.

Comment: @Did thanks for the hint!